# "Network Path was not found" SQl Exception (0x80131904) .. Named pipe provider error 40 could not open connection with SQL server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012

I developed an asp project on my local computer and everything worked perfectly until I wanted to move the project to a server (Windows Server 2012)

Simple Asp.net pages run flawless but once I try to connect to out SQL Server we get the error

```
"Network Path was not found"
SQl Exception (0x80131904) .. Named pipe provider error 40 could not open connection with SQL server
```

My connection string is defined in the web config file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="conString" connectionString="Data Source=WIN-XXXXXXXXXXX; Initial Catalog=YYY; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

A simple test asp pages which uses a SqlDataSource  and a Gridview works fine!

```
SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conString").ConnectionString
```

But when I try to use my Sql Connection in the code behind I get an error. It can not be the connection String as it is exactly the same used in the SqlDataSource Object earlier.

```
connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conString").ConnectionString)
connection.open()
```

+some SQL 
throws the error.

Note: This is the first time I am trying to set up a server myself, and after hours of trying things out I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: is there any user name /password to connect to SQL server ?

Comment: Not in the connection string but we have configured the ISS Server's App pool to use the Administrator's identity + passwort for the application.

Comment: Give username and password in connection string and it should connect.

Comment: I tried to add the username and password  <add name="conString" connectionString="Data Source=WIN-XXXXXXXXXXX; Initial Catalog=YYY; Integrated Security=True; User ID=Administrator;Password=XXX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
With both Integrated Security True or SSPI but both did not change the outcome of anything. I noticed that if I but an unvalid value in Integrated Security the default page which worked earlier gives me an error saying that the key for integrated security is wrong but the normal page still gives me the network path error.Why does the DataSource Work but not the Cli

Answer (score 0):

Enable TCP/IP,Named Pipes In  sql server configuration manager.Expand Sql Native client 11.0 Configuration manager. In client protocols you will see TCP/IP, named Pipes,Via disabled, enable those,Expand Server Network Configuration In Protocols for Sql Server here  Enable Shared,Named,TCP/IP,Expand Sql Native client 11.0 Configuration manager. and restart the services For more info Refer this Link [Named Pipes Error 40](http://microsoft-sql-ssis.blogspot.in/2015/09/how-to-fix-named-pipes-provider-error.html)